# can't start mysql service anymore

Tags: 12.04, mysql, services

I had MySQL running ... with many different databases.  I install MySQL workbench today.. and was able to create any entity relationship diagram etc. 
Then i decided to increase the size of my max_allowed_packet setting and restart the service.  Unfortunately, the service wouldn't restart.  I checked my syslog and I'm getting the following errors:

```
 Sep 17 14:48:30 dev kernel: [456044.062568] init: mysql main process
 (8723) terminated with status 1  Sep 17 14:48:30 dev kernel:
 [456044.062606] init: mysql main process ended, respawning Sep 17
 14:48:31 dev kernel: [456045.071308] init: mysql post-start process
 (8724) terminated with status 1  Sep 17 14:48:31 dev kernel:
 [456045.080818] type=1400 audit(1379443711.030:42): apparmor="STATUS"
 operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=8749
 comm="apparmor_parser"  Sep 17 14:48:31 dev kernel: [456045.094878]
 init: mysql main process (8753) terminated with status 1  Sep 17
 14:48:31 dev kernel: [456045.094911] init: mysql main process ended,
 respawning Sep 17 14:48:32 dev kernel: [456046.103060] init: mysql
 post-start process (8754) terminated with status 1  Sep 17 14:48:32
 dev kernel: [456046.112910] type=1400 audit(1379443712.062:43):
 apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
 pid=8777 comm="apparmor_parser"  Sep 17 14:48:32 dev kernel:
 [456046.128208] init: mysql main process (8781) terminated with status
 1  Sep 17 14:48:32 dev kernel: [456046.128240] init: mysql respawning
 too fast, stopped
```

I found another post on this site with a similar question and it suggested running **dpkg-reconfigure.**

Here's the results:

```
jm@dev:/var/log$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
[sudo] password for jm: 
Warning: World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' is ignored
130917 14:52:57 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130917 14:52:57 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130917 14:52:57 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
130917 14:52:57 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
130917 14:52:57 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130917 14:52:57 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130917 14:52:57 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
130917 14:52:58  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130917 14:52:59 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 477426000
130917 14:52:59 [Warning] Neither --relay-log nor --relay-log-index were used; so replication may break when this MySQL server acts as a slave and has his hostname changed!! Please use '--relay-log=dev-relay-bin' to avoid this problem.
130917 14:52:59 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: File './dev-relay-bin.index' not found (Errcode: 13)
130917 14:52:59 [ERROR] Failed in open_log() called from init_relay_log_info()
130917 14:52:59 [ERROR] Failed to initialize the master info structure
130917 14:52:59  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130917 14:52:59  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 477426000
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
jm@dev:/var/log$
```

Any suggestions on how to fix would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Warning: World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' is ignored

There is your problem. You changed persmissions on the file so you could edit it and MySQL refuses to let you use it.

Permissions should be:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3505 apr 22 09:56 my.cnf
```

Nothing more.